# Javascript or jQuery is caching my javascript variable. How do I reset this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an AJAX call as such :

```
    $('a.delete_task').live('click', function() {
      $this = $(this);

      function deleteFunction(){            

        var obj = $this.parents('.task');
        $(obj).addClass('highlighted');

        $.post($this.attr('href'), { _method: 'delete' }, function(data) {
          if ( $single_item_collection == true ) {
          } else {
          };
        });
      };

      SSK.confirm_delete($this, deleteFunction, "task");
      return false;
    });
```

And then I take my `deleteFunction()` and throw it into the `delete_confirmation` :

```
$(function(){
  window.SSK = new(Class.extend({
  confirm_delete: function(obj, action, label){
    $(".confirm-deletion").live("click", function(){
      action.call(obj);
      $(this).parents("#delete-message").fadeOut();
      return false;
    });
  },
```

The problem is that when I click it the first time it works. When I click it the second time, it passes through the first `$(this)`, and the second `$(this)`. Likewise, when I click another item for a third time, it tries and pass all three and so on.

Somehow it is caching `$(this)`. As crazy as that is. And passing it everytime the method is passed again.

Confirm delete as a function creates a popup and passes the method of the link you originally clicked to it as the variable `obj`.

Then if you click confirm it does this :

```
    $(".confirm-deletion").live("click", function(){
      action.call(obj);
      $(this).parents("#delete-message").fadeOut();
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: Can you include a bit more of your code?  It sounds to me like you're binding a new click handler every time and so each time an additional handler is attached.  Then clicking on it fires all of the clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a click event to the element 'confirm-deletion' every single time the user clicks 'delete_task'. That's why the click event is firing multiple times, it's literally been added multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's surely not crazy caching. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and rewrite `confirm_delete` and/or `deleteFunction`.

I'm quite sure that you need to put `$(this)` in a caching value in the click-handler closure, and then use that in `deleteFunction`.

Comment: I turned $(this) into $this, and now it sends the **same** thing as many times as I have clicked on the page. So instead of the past 3 for the 3rd click, it passes 3 of the current events.